# How to raise multiple toasts using bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, toastr

I want to raise multiple toasts where the number of toasts are not known in advance.

The examples I see, have the html sections hardcoded in advance.
For example `[here][1]` the html code for the 2 notifications is hard-coded. 
I can inject html code from within Javascript but I find it cumbersome to have to handle all that myself.

I found another library [toastr](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html) where you can add more toast messages simply by calling from within javascript

```
toastr.success('Success messages');
toastr.error('errors messages');
```

I'm trying to avoid adding other libraries, as I am already using Bootstrap, and I want to keep the payload small.

**Can I set dynamic number of Toasts using Bootstrap 4, e.g. similar to the toastr library?**

Thanks,
Avi

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using toastr. The payload is ~10KB for the minified version (toastr.min.css toastr.min.js)